# Как узнать время в секундах от 1970 года в Android?

Tags: таймер, время, android, java

Хочу сделать таймер, как узнать время в секундах от 1970 года? и уже от этого засекать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());    
    long millis = currentDate.getTime();
```

Comment: Достаточно просто Long currentDate =  new Date().getTime(); Конструктор по-умолчанию берет текущую дату